# S3 Cloudfront - Redirects to the file path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured Cloudfront & S3 to redirect my page such that when the user loads www.example.com, it redirects to https://example.com.

When I load the page for url www.example.com it redirects to https://www.example.com.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html. Any idea what am I missing here? I did generate an SSL cert for both example.com and www.example.com. The cloudfront is updated for both www.example.com and example.com.

For www.example.com

The origin domain name path: `www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
Origin id is S3-www.example.com

For example.com

The origin domain name path: `example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
Origin id is `S3-example.com`

For S3 bucket: www.example.com is redirected to example.com using static website setting - checking `Redirect all requests to another host name`

**Update**

I had two distribution settings. One for www.example.com & another for example.com

The https characters are in red with a exclamation mark. (invalid cert) But the certificates are valid

Yes the bucket is recently created and its in the us-west-2 region.

I also created two route 53 Alias records. One for example.com and another for www.example.com 
Each points to its own cloud front distribution.

Comment: The easiest way to redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` would be to use a `CNAME` record in Route 53 (or your DNS server). Or does this cause problems with your HTTPS? Does `www.example.com` currently point to your CloudFront distribution? If so, what do you mean when you say "it redirects to"? Any clarification you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a bucket that was very recently created?  There's a known issue that causes exactly this situation to occur for a short period of time after a bucket is created, if the bucket is behind CloudFront and the bucket is in a region other than us-east-1.